# injecting an generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, decoupling

ok I'm little lost with generics in C#

I have this generic interface

```
interface IInvoiceStorage<T>
    where T : class
{
    void Persist(T Invoice);
}
```

with two classes implementing the interface

```
public class FacturaStorageForSQLServer:IInvoiceStorage<EVT>
{
      public void Persist(EVT Invoice)
      {
        /*Implementation*/
      }
}



public class FacturaStorageForMySQLServer:IInvoiceStorage<EVTFruit>
{
      public void Persist(EVTFruit Invoice)
      {
         /*Implementation*/
      }
}
```

The problem comes when I want to declare this in my service class

```
public class invoice_service
{
   IInvoiceStorage Storage;
   public invoice_service(IInvoiceStorage storage)
   {
     Storage=_storage;
   }
}
```

C# tells me that I have to declare de type of the interface but if I do that then my service class is going to depend from the implementation and not from the interface.

Suggestions??

**UPDATE 1:**
Sorry If I declare the type the interface is going to depend only from the implementations using that type but what happens if I have two implementations using two different types for example EVT and EVTFruit.

I was thinking  to use another interface to establish a relationship between EVT and EVTFruit but they can be two totally different objects so I'm not sure if it is a good idea.

Comment: You need to declare the interface's type parameter, IInvoiceStorage<EVTFruit>, not the type of the actual implementation of that interface.

Comment: What sort of objects are you planning to  pass into `Storage.Persist()` in your `invoice_service` class? And how would those objects' types relate to `EVTFruit` and `EVT`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change your class a little bit:

```
public class invoice_service<T> where T : class
{
   IInvoiceStorage<T> Storage;
   public invoice_service(IInvoiceStorage<T> storage)
   {
     Storage=_storage;
   }
}
```

Which would allow you to use the interface correctly and keep it generic.

Comment: making the caller generic doesn't sound bad

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, you could also defined non-generic version of that interface:

```
public interface IInvoiceStorage
{
  ...
}
```

And make classes inherit from this interface, too.

```
public class FacturaStorageForSQLServer : IInvoiceStorage, IInvoiceStorage<EVT>
public class FacturaStorageForMySQLServer : IInvoiceStorage, IInvoiceStorage<EVTFruit>
```

That way you can use non-generic version of interface in `invoice_service` class.

But, as I said, depending on your needs if you can make functionality of that interface independent of type (for example, `List<T>` also implements `IList` for list functionalities, without type).

Comment: This is a nice idea but as you said I will have to make functionality of that interface

Comment: Methods of non-generic interface can be a subset of a generic interface. Basicaly, both non-generic and generic interface provide you with all the functionalities.

Comment: Ok but there is a little problem. If I use a non-generic interface  in invoice_service class. I wil only have access to the methods of the non-generic interface.

Comment: Yes, that is why I said that this is depending on your business needs, if this suites you. Maybe you can present all your methods in your non-generic interface. You should then review your design if you actually need generic interface. Other solution would be that of Ron Beyer in which your invoice_service is also generic.

Comment: You could also make some more restrictions on your T type, e.g. to make it implement some other interface and use it in generic constraint. e.g. "where T : class, IPersistor" or something like that. Then you could use IInvoiceStorage<IPersistor> as an input parameter to your invoice_service.

Answer (score 0):

After trying your suggestions and reading some blogs here is what I did and is fulfilling my requeriments at least for now. The problem was resolved when I realized that I shouldn't use the generic repository pattern as a repository itself but as a helper of the repository! At the end what I'm doing is wrapping the generic interfaces inside of another layer of non-generic interfaces.

a Service class calling for an IInvoiceRepositoryService implementation

```
public class InvoiceService
{
   private IInvoiceRepositoryService RepositoryService;
   public SQLInvoiceService(IInvoiceRepositoryService _RS)
   {
       RepositoryService=_RS;
   }
}
```

and their respective implementation for EVT and EVTFruit.

```
public class EVTRepository:IInvoiceRepositoryService
{
  private IInvoiceStorage<EVT> EVTStorage;

  public EVTInvoiceRepository(IInvoice<EVT> _EVT)
  {
    EVTStorage=_EVT;
  }
}


public class EVTStorageForSQLServer: IInvoiceStorage<EVT>
{
   /*Implementation*/
}

public class EVTStorageForMySQLServer: IInvoiceStorage<EVT>
{
   /*Implementation*/
}



public class EVTFruitRepository:IInvoiceRepositoryService
{
  private IInvoiceStorage<EVT> EVTFruitStorage;

  public EVTFruitInvoiceRepository(IInvoice<EVTFruit> _EVTFruit)
  {
    EVTFruitStorage=_EVTFruit;
  }
}

public class EVTFruitStorageForSQLServer: IInvoiceStorage<EVTFruit>
{
   /*Implementation*/
}

public class EVTFruitStorageForMySQLServer: IInvoiceStorage<EVTFruit>
{
   /*Implementation*/
}
```

At the end this was just a design problem I think. I'm going to mark Ron Beyer's response as the answer because is valid and it was really straightforward